# Excel SQL import - Error 3704 Operation not allowed when object is closed

Tags: sql, excel, vba

When trying to execute a sub in an Excel model I receive an error message saying:

> *Operation not allowed when object is closed.*

I have written code like this before in order to import data from a SQL database and never had any problems. I'm guessing the issue with this sub is that the sql query is making a temporary table, with a result from a stored procedure, of which I just want the 4 most recent data points.

The sub looks like this:

```vb
Sub sqlImport()

Dim dbConn As ADODB.connection
Set dbConn = New ADODB.connection

dbConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Network=dbmssocn;Initial Catalog=Funds;Data Source=" & Data_Source_Prod02
dbConn.CursorLocation = adUseServer
dbConn.Open

'Define cell - top left in table
Dim startCell As Range
Set startCell = Import.Range("tableTopLeft")

'Clear the table
Range(startCell, startCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).ClearContents

'Setup SQL import
Dim CmdSP As New ADODB.Command
CmdSP.CommandType = adCmdText
CmdSP.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE #tmpBus2 (FundID INT, PortfolioDate date, TotalFundValueBillionSEK float, NAVSEK float, FundShares float)" & _
                    "INSERT INTO #tmpBus2 EXEC Funds.Analysi.Fund_Size @FundId = 4235 " & _
                    "SELECT TOP 4 PortfolioDate, NAVSEK, FundShares FROM #tmpBus2 ORDER BY PortfolioDate DESC"
CmdSP.ActiveConnection = dbConn

'Execute command
Dim dbList As ADODB.Recordset
Set dbList = CmdSP.Execute

'Print table data
Dim row As Integer, col As Integer
row = 1
While Not dbList.EOF
    For col = 0 To dbList.Fields.Count - 1
        startCell.Offset(row, col) = dbList(col)
    Next col

    dbList.MoveNext
    row = row + 1
Wend

dbConn.Close

End Sub
```

The error occurs at

```
While Not dbList.EOF
```

Anyone have a solution?

I can't rewrite the stored procedure. And the result I get from the stored procedure is quite a big dataset, that's why I want to just select the top 4 rows.